# Take symbols from right until dot

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to take last numbers of {{ansible_default_ipv4.address}}. I want to take symbols from right until dot.

For example, I want to take "2" from 192.168.0.2 or "14" from 192.168.0.14 or "254" from 192.168.0.254

But I don't know how I can do that.
Did anyone do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure Jinja2:

- [split the string into a list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)
- select the last element of the list

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ '192.168.1.2'.split('.')[-1] }}"
```